# Ubuntu Installation alongside with windows 10 in Dell XPS8900 crashes with Low disk space message

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 16.10 in my Dell XPS8900 alongside windows10. I have free space (unallocated) of about 350GB. After following all the steps (creating a UEFI Usb boot, starting in recovery mood, boot from USB, selecting ubuntu alongside windows 10) the OS installation starts. But just after selecting the timezone it says low disk space and the installation crashes.(I think it is not related with timezone, but somehow the installation can not find sufficient space)

There is 350GB free space and later I have checked that two partitions are created by ubuntu installation which indicates it is identifying the free space. But Still installation crashes with low disk space as the reason.

Following the same process, I have installed Ubuntu alongside windows 10 at my laptop.(Lenovo). But it is not working for my desktop.(Dell xps 8900) I have tried at least 10 times with different options.

Please help.

Comment: Is the "free space" already allocated to windows? Make sure during the ubuntu installation that the 'after' allocation shows a windows partition LESS THAN 350Gb, a ubuntu partition (usually sda1) of at least 8Gb, more is better though and you'll probably have a swap partition (mine is usually sda5) equal to the amount of ram in your system. You may need to manually specify the partition sizes. See this page here for a guide [http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html)